# Render props in child component not showing on screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to React Native and I made a stateless component to loop over props which are objects that each contain an array of tags.

I then return a single tag from each array item. (Console logged in screenshot)

[image]

However, when I call the function renderTags() and try to return the {tag} nothing is rendered to the screen.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

    const Tags = (props) => {
      console.log('props', props);
      function renderTags () {
        // Loop over each object. Object contains an array.
        for (let i of Object.keys(props)) {
          console.log(props[i]);
          // Loop over each array item to return a single tag
          props[i].forEach(tag => {
            console.log(tag);
            return (
              <TouchableHighlight style={{backgroundColor: '#ede7f6',
                borderRadius: 4,
                paddingTop: 4,
                paddingBottom: 4,
                paddingRight: 4,
                paddingLeft: 4,
                marginRight: 4}}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize:12 }}>{tag}</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              );
          });
        }
      }
      return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10}}>
          {renderTags()}
        </View>
      );
    };
    export {Tags};
```

I'm not getting any errors or warnings in the logs or console so I'm really not sure why this isn't rendering. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderTags` as currently implemented returns `undefined`. Returning from `forEach` doesn't make sense.

Should be something like this

```
function renderTags () {
    return [...Object.keys(props).map(key => props[key].map(tag => (
      <TouchableHighlight style={{backgroundColor: '#ede7f6',
                borderRadius: 4,
                paddingTop: 4,
                paddingBottom: 4,
                paddingRight: 4,
                paddingLeft: 4,
                marginRight: 4}}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize:12 }}>{tag}</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
    )))]

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Yury. That makes a lot more sense! :)

Comment: @LaurieWilliams No problem. BTW you might also want to check if `props[key]` is array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use map instead of forEach. Cause, forEach doesn't return value, that work just iterate your array or iterable object. But map returns an array that contains your logical outputs.

If a react component renders that want a single component instance, or an array of component instances.